# C program solving parametric equations

Tags: c, matrix, linear-algebra, linear-equation

Let's say you have **N** equations with **M** parameters. Task is to find if there is any solution. If there is, which one. If there are more solutions, how do you describe them ?

**example**:

1) x + y + z = 1

2)     y + z = 4

Matrix form:

( 1 1 1 | 1 )

( 0 1 1 | 4 )

Array in C:

```
double arr[2][3] = { {1, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 4} };
```

Expected output (one of infinite number of possible solutions):

*(-3, 2, 2) + { (-3, 4-z, z) }*

I'am able to use "gaussian elimination" to convert matrix into "nice" form which human can easily see and calculate solution. However I'am stuck on **finding expected output**.

I have arr[N][M] which represents matrix in "nice" form. (Note that N does not have to be equal M, thus there can be infinite number of sulution). Is there **any algorithm** to deduce solution ?

===============

EDIT: Matrix is in [row echelon form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RN1rf.jpg)

Comment: Do you have to show the human-readable solving progress? If no (that is, just need to show the solution), then you can directly use ratio of det(some_matrix) to find out the solution.

Comment: Only solution is needed. No "How did you get that solution".

Comment: You can see [Cramer's Rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule), which is the general solution for linear systems, and seems easier to implement by program rather than Gaussian Elimination. Remember to handle the situation of dividing by zero (that is, maybe infinity solution sets).

Comment: *convert matrix into "nice" form which human can easily see and calculate solution* What would that form be?

Comment: Don't know the exact name in english, but it is very similat to "matrix triangular form". Matrix in my example is in this form. EDIT: Matrix is in row echelon form

Comment: English name *"reduced row echelon form"*, see [Gaussian elimination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination)

Comment: Why not start with a simple search to point you in the right direction? E.g. [C Program for Gauss Elimination Method](https://www.codewithc.com/c-program-for-gauss-elimination-method/) and [Gaussian Elimination to Solve Linear Equations](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gaussian-elimination/) (just change the headers to `stdio.h` and `stdlib.h` and get rid of `using namespace std;`)

Comment: I've seen these posts before creating this topic. Problem is that they assume matrix N x N, where my solution should work for M x N matrix.

Comment: `M x N` linearly independent matrices, when `M != N`, have insufficient constraints to give you a solution or have no solution. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors

Comment: It isn't very clear what your expected output is. Is it the literal string `(-3, 4-z, z)`  or any string of the form `(-3, 4-z, z)` where a number is substituted for `z`? Please show a literal string you want to see.